# Pick out matches in this pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out a regular expression which can cope with the following conditions:

Basically, the line below is a key pair of variables and their values, expressed in a line of text.

1. The variable name can be A-Za-z0-9
2. A comma separates pairs
3. The value can be anything, including equals and comma

`Variable1=somevalue1,Variable2=somevalue2,Variable3=some,value2`

I would expect the following matches:

1. `Variable1=somevalue1`
2. `Variable2=somevalue2`
3. `Variable3=some,value2`

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Cant be done with the structure you want. You say a comma can be included in each value, but that it also delimits records. For instance, how would it know that `value2` is infact part of `variable3` and not the start of another variable? You should use another character to delimit your records to avoid ambiguity

Comment: If a value can be anything and a variable name can be any combination of A-Za-z0-9 there's no way to distinguish between a value and a new variable declaration. Example: `variable3=some,value2=2,variable4=foo`. Which is a value and which is a variable declaration?

Answer (score 5):

Your requirement isn't deterministic and therefore you'll not have a single result and a regular expression will not handle your needs.

For instance, your sample can have the following results:

- Match1

  - Variable1 => somevalue1,Variable2=somevalue2,Variable3=some,value2
- Match2

  - Variable1 => somevalue1
  - Variable2 => somevalue2,Variable3=some,value2
- Match3

  - Variable1 => somevalue1,Variable2=somevalue2
  - Variable3 => some,value2

and so on.

Therefor I recommend considering having quotes for the value or other kind of variable separation.

Comment: I also considered having quotes, still undecided if this is the best way. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

There is a way of doing it, but it's not reliable and this relies on that a variable *must* begin with a capital letter. Also it will (semi-)fail if in the value exists a `,` followed directly by a capital letter
`([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)\s*=\s*(.*?)(?=,[A-Z]|$)`

So what do we have here ?

- `([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)` : group and match a string that starts with a capital letter, and match zero or more times letters and digits.
- `\s*=\s*` : match white spaces optionally and then an equal sign and then white spaces optionally.
- `(.*?)` : group and match everything, ungreedy.
- `(?=,[A-Z]|$)` : Positive lookahead, check if `.*?` is followed by a `comma and a capital letter` or `end of line`.

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/cQ9mF9)

> <sub>**Regex is awesome isn't it ?**</sub>

Comment: this is a great solution- however i have thousands of lines of this kind of text in different places- so changing it is not feasible. Top marks though!

Comment: @TomBeech check [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GE4d7U) by [DaveRandom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/9844932#9844932)

Answer (score 1):

I partial solved this by traversing the string in reverse, getting a substring from the last equals to the end of the string as the value, then for the variable name, removing as i go, and repeating until all variables are processed.

I had to make one concession, and that is if users want to use an equals in their variable value, they must use a special value !!EQUALS!! which i then replace when the value is instantiated in the VariableValue class

A performance test parsing 1000 lines in this manor took 0.0019 seconds. so its pretty quick.

The 'extract' method on string is an extension method I wrote which outputs a substring, and returns the original string, with the matched substring removed.

```
        public List<VariableValue> ExtractVariables(string line)
        {
            var variables = new List<VariableValue>();

            while (line != string.Empty)
            {
                // Get the value 
                var value = string.Empty;
                var lastEquals = line.LastIndexOf('=') + 1;
                line = line.Extract(lastEquals, line.Length - lastEquals, out value);

                // Get the variable
                var variable = string.Empty;
                var lastComma = line.LastIndexOf(',') + 1;
                line = line.Extract(lastComma, line.Length - lastComma - 1, out variable);

                // Add to list of results
                variables.Add(new VariableValue(variable, value));

                // Remove the trailing bits
                line = (line == "=")
                           ? string.Empty
                           : line.Remove(line.LastIndexOf(','), line.Length - line.LastIndexOf(','));
            }

            variables.Reverse();
            return variables;
        }
```

What do you think of my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously values that contain your delimiters are problematic.

However, they can be sensibly handled, as long as your keys cannot contain these delimiters. The recipe for the secret sauce goes something like this:

```
/(?:,|^)(?=[^,]+=)/
```

First we assert that there is either a comma or the beginning of the string, followed by no commas up to the next equals sign. In effect, this splits on the *last* comma in a given key/value pair.

Then we just loop the results and split on the first equals sign.

So we end up with (obviously translated to you language of choice, I've used PHP but what matters is the logic):

```
<?php

    $str = 'Variable1=somevalue1,Variable2=somevalue2,Variable3=some,value2';

    $result = [];
    foreach (preg_split('/(?:,|^)(?=[^,]+=)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $item) {
        $item = explode('=', $item, 2);
        $result[$item[0]] = isset($item[1]) ? $item[1] : '';
    }

    print_r($result);
```

Which produces:

```
Array
(
    [Variable1] => somevalue1
    [Variable2] => somevalue2
    [Variable3] => some,value2
)
```

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5wlTKe)

Comment: thanks for your answer- it seems the best. however i cannot get that regular expression working in .NET             string s = "Variable1=somevalue1,Variable2=somevalue2,Variable3=some,value2";
            
            foreach (var pair in Regex.Split(s, "/(?:,|^)(?=[^,]+=)/"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pair);
            }

Comment: @TomBeech I think you would need to remove the leading/trailing `/` from the expression for .NET, IIRC it doesn't use delimiters like PCRE does. So you would use simply `(?:,|^)(?=[^,]+=)`